# Makefile skips dependency

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've created a makefile for my little project

```
.SUFFIXES:

%.cpp:
    $(COMP) -c -o $(subst .cpp,.o,$@) $(SRCDIR)$@ $(CFLAGS)

platformL: COMP:=gcc
platformL: $(FILES)
    $(COMP) -o $(NAME) $(subst .cpp,.o,$(FILES)) $(CFLAGS)
    rm $(subst .cpp,.o,$(FILES))

platformW: COMP:=wine gcc
platformW: $(FILES)
    $(COMP) -o $(NAME).exe $(subst .cpp,.o,$(FILES)) $(CFLAGS)
    rm $(subst .cpp,.o,$(FILES))

default: platformL platformW
    echo Done!
```

Everything worked fine until I branched to 2 different platforms, 'make' command executes only my platformL branch. After spending some time with it I discovered that adding '.PHONY' won't fix the problem. Also, it appears that only the first branch from the top gets executed (I have put the lines of platformW before platformL and only Windows compilation was performed).

How can I make it execute both branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make always builds the first explicit target (and all prerequisites of the first explicit target) in the makefile, by default.  That's all it will build by default.

You can either specify multiple things to build on the command line, like `make platformL platformW`, or you can add a new first target that depends on all the other targets you want built.  By tradition that target is named `all` but you can call it whatever you want:

```
all: platformL platformW
.PHONY: all

  ...
platformL: ...
  ...
platformW: ...
```